# Vertical align in header elements

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I know this got asked a lot here, but all the methods I am trying seem not to work for my code for some reason.

I want to vertically align the text in the elements

**HTML:**

```
<div id="mainWrapper">
    <div id="header"> 
        <div id="logo" class="headerElements">
            <h:outputText class="headerText" value="RedPrice" />
        </div>
        <div id="login" class="headerElements">
            <h:outputText class="headerText" value="Login" />
        </div>
        <div id="register" class="headerElements">
            <h:outputText class="headerText" value="Register" />
        </div>
        <div id="follow" class="headerElements">
            <h:outputText class="headerText" value="Follow us" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

body,html {
    height: 100%;
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
}

div#mainWrapper {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: url(../images/women.jpg) no-repeat center center;
}

div#header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 5%;
    background: white;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

div.headerElements {
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 10%;
    text-align: center;
}

div.headerElements:hover {
    background: orangered;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.headerText {
    font-size: x-large; 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/E7DAe/

What I have already tried: (unsuccesfully)

- setting line-height to 100% in headerElems
- setting `display: table-cell`
- putting it into a `ul` and `lis` and setting display:table and display:table-cell

Can somebody provide me with a solution?

Comment: what does that h: tag mean in ur code?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use

```
div.headerElements:before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/E7DAe/2/) (Note: I have increased wrapper's height to see it better)

Based on http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/, read it for a full explanation.

Comment: I upvoted, but then removed as unfortunately this isn't working for me for multi-line text. I'm going to re-upvote as it's a great fix for single line text. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I ended up using flex container.  So in this example, change the CSS for div#mainWrapper to this:

```
div#mainWrapper {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: url(../images/women.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is another suggestion, but I am not certain I understand the question.

```
div {
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XXyp2/

Comment: I use this solution commonly. It's so simple,

Answer (score 2):

Yo can use this way also -

1 :- Html part

```
<div>
    <h1>try me</h1>
</div>
```

2 :- Css Part

```
div {
  background: #000;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  height: 30px;
  display: table; 
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

div > h1 {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The most simple and easy to use solution imo.. also the safest unless you're support `IE8` is:

**HTML**

```
<h2>
    <span>30 mins</span>
</h2>
```

**CSS**

```
h2 {
    height: 120px;
    position: relative;
}

h2 span {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

**Mr Fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/hutber/wpmtkwkL/

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your actual css "div.headerElements" by this one (just deleted "float: left;"):

```
div.headerElements {
    height: 100%;
    width: 10%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/E7DAe/3/

Comment: I think he means he wants to vertically align the text inside the wrapping element along the horizontal line. Not vertically align all the elements.

Comment: Well why not? At an extra cost SO does provide the neural enhancement of mind reading ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `clear:both;` to achieve that. Something like this:

```
div.headerElements {
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  width: 10%;
  clear: both;
  text-align: center;
}
```

[Check this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/leonardorb/E7DAe/1/) to illustrate this implementation.